# long splited php script

Tags: php, refresh, long-integer

I have a long script in php, due to timeout problems : I'm trying to split it and refresh the page constantly (after any task is done)

I found a script on the net allowing that.
So I'm expermenting it with simple loop function sleep(1)

```
<?php

// PRINCIPE :
// Le script est executé par tranches afin de ne pas surcharger
// le serveur.

// CONFIGURATION :
// Temps d'execution maximum d'une "tranche" en secondes
$tempsExecMax = 2;
// Temps d'attente entre chaque "tranche" en millisecondes
$tempsRepos = 100;

/*  ----------------------------------------------------------
    Placez dans cette fonction le script à executer
        retour :
    Retourne une valeur qui sera utilisée pour relancer le
    script (valeur start lors de la prochaine execution de
    la fonction).
    Si cette valeur vaut -1, alors l'execution du
    script est terminée.
        start :
    Valeur repérant la valeur renvoyée par l'execution
    précédente de la fonction Script. Si cette valeur vaut 0,
    alors il s'agit de la première execution de cette fonction.
    Cette valeur n'est qu'un repère pour mémoriser
    l'avancement de l'execution, elle n'est pas utilisée hors
    de cette fonction. Elle peut donc représenter
    n'importe quoi.
        tempsExec :
    Temps maximum d'execution de la fonction. Si la fonction
    atteint cette limite, elle se termine et renvoie une
    valeur de retour.
    ----------------------------------------------------------  */
function Script( $start, $tempsExec )
{
    // Repère le temps d'execution de la fonction
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
    $start_time=(float)$usec + (float)$sec;
    $new_time = $start_time;
    $t = 1;
    sleep(1);
    while ($new_time - $start_time < $tempsExec)
    {
        sleep(1);
        $t++;
        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
        $new_time=(float)$usec + (float)$sec;
    }
    return $t;
    //  ----------------------------------------------------------
}

ob_start();
header("Expires: Mon, 1 Dec 2003 01:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Script longue durée</title>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-LANGUAGE" content="FR"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache/"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1"/>
</head>

<body style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 12px">
    <p style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 30px">
        Exécution d'un script de longue durée
        par découpage et relancement automatique.
    </p>
    <div>
        <p>
            Avancement de l'exécution :
            <?php
                // On récupère l'avancement du script
                $run = 0;
                if (isset($_GET['run'])) $run = $_GET['run'];
                $start = 0;
                if (isset($_GET['start'])) $start = $_GET['start'];
                // Affichage de l'avancement actuel
                if ($run == 1)
                {
                    echo $start;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Exécution non démarrée';
                }
                // Appel du script
                $start = Script( $start, $tempsExecMax );
                // Si exécution terminée
                if (($run==1) and ($start == -1))
                {
                    echo '<br><b>Exécution terminée</b>';
                }
            ?>
        </p>

        <?php
            // Si l'execution n'est pas démarrée ou est terminée
            if (($run != 1) or ($start == -1))
            {
                // On propose de la démarrer
                ?>
                    <p style="font-weight: bold">
                        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?start=0&amp;run=1"
                            title="Lancer le script">
                            Démarrer l'exécution du script</a>
                    </p>
                <?php
            }
            else
            // Si l'execution est lancée, on la continue
            {
                // Si l'execution n'est pas terminée
                if ($start > -1)
                {
                    // Relancement du script
                    if ($tempsRepos != 0)
                    {
                        ?>
                            <p>
                                Attente de
                                <?php echo $tempsRepos; ?> millisecondes
                                avant la reprise de l'execution.
                            </p>
                        <?php
                    }
                    echo ("<script language=\"JavaScript\"
                        type=\"text/javascript\">window.setTimeout('location.href=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?start=$start&run=1\";',500+$tempsRepos);
                        </script>\n");
                    echo ("<noscript>\n");
                    echo ("<p><a href=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?start=$start&run=1\">Cliquez ici pour continuer</a> (Activez JavaScript pour le faire automatiquement)</p>\n");
                    echo ("</noscript>\n");

                    echo ("<p><b><a href=\"".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."\">Arrêter l'exécution du script</a></b></p>\n");
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    <p style="font-size: 11px; margin-top: 50px; text-indent: 0px; text-align: center">
        Par <a title="Mon site web" href="http://matthieu.napoli.free.fr/">
            Matthieu Napoli<a/>
    </p>
</body>
```

But I'm getting a problem : Avancement de l'exÃ©cution : 2 **stops at 2**

Comment: In your `while` loop you are missing a `;` after `$t++`

Comment: Thanks for noticing please see edits I have another problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,
I don't really understand what you want to do with this script.
When I execute it on my side, I have :

```
Avancement de l'exécution : 0
```

Then it's reload, and :

```
Avancement de l'exécution : 2
```

Then it's reload, and :

```
Avancement de l'exécution : 2
```

again. And this value will stay to 2 until I stop the script.

So, if you want the script to automatically stop, you must increment or decrement it's $start value.

When you first click on `Démarrer l'exécution du script`, $start = 0 and $run = 1 ; but your function is not correct, the parameter $start is not used on it, so it will always return 2 ($tempsExec value, defined in configuration part).

You should review the original script, I think you delete something important for it's properly working.

Comment: I arranged the script

Answer (score 0):

Try this first instruction in your php file that will allow you to change the timeout time of the request :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', XX);
```

With XX in seconds. By default, php script are timed out after 30 seconds. You could change this value. Set to 0 for no limit, but WARNING it's not recommended. You can set this value to 0, then calculate amount of time you need to execute this script, and then change this value to the max time you have to execute script +10%

Comment: My script is for cleaning a giant database, it must take approximately 1 or 2 hours, so I will use it as cron job, but unfortunately changing all timeout parametres doesn't solve my problem due to limitations on the server, I'm on hostgator baby plan, that's why I'm experimenting this script to use it.

Comment: PHP is may be not appropriate to clean very big database. You should try to have a look at your DBMS for an appropriate solution. I'll post another answer for your specific request with PHP later

Comment: Thanks please don't forget, I will be gladly waiting your response

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull with `while loops`, it can get stuck. The problem in your `while loops`. Try to change this: `$new_time - $start_time < $tempsExec`. I guess `$new_time - $start_time` will never be bigger than `$tempsExec`.

Comment: I increased $tempsExec to 29 seconds

Comment: I hope this will help (add $t to condition): `while ((($new_time - $start_time) < $tempsExec) || $t < 50)`. This will do 50 loops and then will stop looping

Comment: yes thanks, but actually when I use another script I notice that it do the same loop each tame without changing parametres, for example sleep($t); $t++;